# Rstan for R versions 3.1.3?

Tags: r, stan, rstan

I cannot get Rstan because my R version is too recent.

```
    > install.packages("rstan")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rstan’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

Is there anyway to download rstan for this version? Do I need to downgrade my R version in order to use rstan?

Comment: You can try  `install.packages("rstan", type="source")`

Comment: Trying this right now, which I found on the getting started page. `source('http://mc-stan.org/rstan/install.R', echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 2000)
install_rstan()`

Comment: @MaratTalipov rstan isn't on CRAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @Dason, rstan is not on CRAN. The line to install rstan is on the getting started [page](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started#how-to-use-rstan). Here is the line:

```
    source('http://mc-stan.org/rstan/install.R', echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 2000)
install_rstan()
```

My apologies for overlooking this.

Reinstalling rstan might fix [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137225/basic-stan-model-failing-with-negative-length-vector-error) issue as well!

Comment: It would probably be best to read through all of this: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I did read it through at one point because I installed rstan a while back. However, I got this weird error (linked in my answer to different question), couldn't figure that out, and then got mixed up trying to reinstall rstan and didn't reread the instructions. You're right of course! But that's the flow of what happened.

Comment: Thanks for the work. I had previously tried to install on one of my Macs and failed and gave up. It now installs (but takes a long time to do so) on OSX 10.7.5 in R 3.1.2 (with the appropriate XCode resources).